# Reading lines from a text file into a pointer array of strings.

Tags: c, string, pointers

I've been all over Stack Exchange and I haven't seen any threads that answer my question, but please direct me to one if I missed it.

I'm using C.

So I've got a text file where the first nine lines are labels (with spaces), and each line after that is nine pieces of data that correspond to those labels. I've declared a pointer array:

```
char * cp_labels[9];
```

And I'm trying to read each of the first 9 lines from the text file into each element of the array.

The text file looks like this:

```
Et jet 1
Et jet 2
Et jet 3
Eta 1
Eta 2
Eta 3
Met
Ht
Njet
(double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double)
(double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double)
(double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double) (double)
...
```

And so on. Right now I'm just trying to make sure the strings are storing in the array correctly. I'm working with this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE *fp_data;
  fp_data = fopen("data.dat", "r");
  char *cp_labels[9];

  for (int l=0;l<9;l++)
    {
      fscanf(fp_data, "%s", cp_labels[l]);

      printf("%s\n", cp_labels[1]);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that

```
fscanf
```

is treating each string as a string (as it should) and I'm trying to get it to treat each line as a string.

```
fgets
```

is an option I'm aware of, but I can't seem to get it to work with a pointer array of strings. Any ideas? I'm doing it this way because I want to be able to use the elements of this array as labels later.

Comment: You need space to read the data into allocated to those pointers.  You also need to use `fgets()` rather than `fscanf()` because you care about lines and `fscanf()` doesn't.  Are you on Linux or a POSIX-ish machine where [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
is an option?  If so, use it.  Failing that, are the first lines always quite short?  If so, you can read lines into a fixed size buffer and then use `strdup()` to copy them into space allocated for those pointers to point at.

Comment: What do you mean you can't "get `fgets` to work"?  Do you have problems with the syntax, or problems with the logic?

Comment: Each `cp_labels[i]` pointer must be allocated before you can read into them. Otherwise, your `fscanf` attempts to read to a buffer pointer that's invalid. `cp_labels` is initially an array of undefined addresses/pointers.

Comment: @lurker how would I allocate an array of strings? Isn't it supposed to be dynamic?

Comment: Using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Glad I came here, never heard of malloc.

Comment: Actually, `strdup` (which internally uses `malloc`) is the way to go as the posted answer shows.

Comment: Looked up strdup and strcspn, think I've got a handle on it now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "data.dat";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    char *cp_labels[9];
    char buffer[4096];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9 && fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0; i++)
    {
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
        cp_labels[i] = strdup(buffer);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        printf("%d: [%s]\n", i, cp_labels[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        free(cp_labels[i]);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output (from your data file):

```
0: [Et jet 1]
1: [Et jet 2]
2: [Et jet 3]
3: [Eta 1]
4: [Eta 2]
5: [Eta 3]
6: [Met]
7: [Ht]
8: [Njet]
```

This uses `fgets()` because it is easy to use and get right.  Using `getline()` is equally easy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "data.dat";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    char *cp_labels[9];
    char *buffer = 0;
    size_t buflen = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9 && getline(&buffer, &buflen, fp) != -1; i++)
    {
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
        cp_labels[i] = buffer;
        buffer = 0;
        buflen = 0;
    }
    free(buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        printf("%d: [%s]\n", i, cp_labels[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        free(cp_labels[i]);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

That produces the same output.